# set a variable that holds array from a function

Tags: php, laravel

Is this a correct syntax or correct approach?

```
function formGroups($forms)
{
    $g_education = $form->groups()->create(['name' => 'Education']);
    $g_engagement = $form->groups()->create(['name' => 'Engagement in early childhood education']);
    return[$g_education, $g_engagement];
}

private function forms()
{
    $form = $this->period('B4 school', 5, 'year', 1, 'year')->periodDomains()->create(['domain_id' => $this->domains()->getKey()]);
    return $form;
}
protected function test($formGroup)
{
    return $this->$formGroup;
}

 $form = $this->forms(); //passing the forms() value to $form
 $formGroup = array($this->formGroups($form));
 $this->educations($formGroup);
 $this->engagements($formGroup);
```

I wanted to pass the value to $formGroup so that I can use the values from the other classes. I am currently getting an error while doing it. Is this the right syntax?

Comment: You have an undefined variable `$form` in `formGroups()` method.

Comment: "_I am currently getting an error while doing it_" Always a good idea to post the complete error message in your question. Please do so

Comment: Call to a member function groups() on array ----

that is the error when I run the seeder